# netbeans: code templates new line

Tags: netbeans, code-templates

To respect [Zend's coding standard](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/PHP+Coding+Standard+%28draft%29#PHPCodingStandard%28draft%29-FunctionandMethodDeclaration) I want to have my methods this way:

```
public function myMethod()
{
    //my code here
}
```

But when I type `fnc` + `CTRL+SPACE` the code template put it like this:

```
public function myMethod() {
    //my code here
}
```

I modified the `fnc` code template like this:

```
function ${functionName}($$${param})
{
    ${selection}${cursor}
}
```

but no change. I've also try:

```
function ${functionName}($$${param})

{
    ${selection}${cursor}
}
```

but then the opening brace at column 1, and not column 4 (as it should be to respect identation).
Does anybody know how to achieve this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is late answer, but maybe you don't find solution yet.

Your problem is related to auto format code after use template.

If you define template at the bottom you have dropdown: On Template Expansion - select "Do nothing" 
or in Options->Editor in dropdown Category select "Braces" and change editor options (then you can use "Reformat Text" in code templates).

Comment: thx Grzedorz, I didn't found the solution, and your's is working fine. Just say that the Category dropdown is in tools->options->editor->formatting